# Need help with count query

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query

I'm currently working with a service with a count query running longer than I want. The query doesn't have serious performance issues but I believe there is an improvement.

Let me provide a little bit of context. There is a table with multiple columns, but I'm focused only on a few. Let's say that the table looks like this:

| id | domain | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | somedomain.com | 1 |
| 2 | subdomain.somedomain.com | 1 |
| 3 | [www.somedomain.com](http://www.somedomain.com) | 1 |
| 4 | test.com | 1 |

As you may notice the first 3 rows in the table have something in common - the domains in 2nd and 3rd rows are subdomains on the domain in 1st row (the root domain). The business department wants us to store the root domain and the subdomains. We have a function inside our database that can remove subdomains from stored domains using some inner rules. For simplicity let's say it does the following work:

```sql
SELECT 
get_root_domain('subdomain.somedomain.com') as domain_1,
get_root_domain('www.somedomain.com') as domain_2
```

| domain_1 | domain_2 |
| --- | --- |
| somedomain.com | somedomain.com |

I'm trying to find the total number of unique domains across the table. For example, in the table below we have only 3 unique domains (according to our business needs) - `somedomain.com` and `test.com`, and `subdomain.somedomain.com`.

To be more precisely the root domain (again, according to our needs) in the table is any domain for which the following rule satisfies:

```sql
domain = get_root_domain(domain) OR domain = 'www.' || get_root_domain(domain)
```

The current solution counts the total number using the following query:

```sql
WITH roots AS (SELECT DISTINCT get_root_domain(domain) as "root_domain"
               FROM user_domains
               WHERE "user_id" = 1
                 AND (domain = get_root_domain(domain) OR domain = 'www.' || get_root_domain(domain))),
     t AS (SELECT first_value("id") OVER w AS "id",
--                some other columns which out of the context
           FROM user_domains ud
                    LEFT JOIN roots r
                              ON get_root_domain(ud.domain) = r."root_domain"
           WHERE ud."user_ud" = 1
           WINDOW w AS ( PARTITION BY (CASE
                                           WHEN r."root_domain" IS NULL THEN ud."id"::TEXT
                                           ELSE format('%s|%s', get_root_domain(ud.domain), ud."status_id") END)
                   ORDER BY length(domain) ))
SELECT count(DISTINCT t."id") AS "count"
FROM t
```

As I said, there are no serious performance issues but the planners say that the left join is the slowest suboperation here. The only reason why I'm looking for another solution is that the query is used to select all fields (I marked them as the comment because they are out of the question context) for another business purpose and the previous team has adopted the query for the counting.

Execution plan: [explain.depesz](https://explain.depesz.com/s/oNkw#html)

Comment: You need to post the results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE. It's more convenient to use this site: https://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: I updated the post and added the link. Thanks for the highlighting!

Comment: I think the problem is simply that the function get_root_domain() is slow. Can you time it by doing EXPLAIN ANALYZE select get_root_domain(domain) FROM user_domains WHERE (set a condition where the domain is not null nor empty and will make the function actually work) LIMIT 100 -- since the table scan will be very fast most of the time should be in the function. If it doesn't take long enough for a proper measurement, increase the LIMIT.

Comment: Your plan in internally inconsistent, and also doesn't match the query you show.

Comment: @jjanes hi! yes, it is and I'm sorry but I thought that posting a production code would be a bad idea so that's why the plan doesn't match the query on 100%.

Comment: @bobflux I run the query against 100k row - https://explain.depesz.com/s/lXrf

Comment: 69 milliseconds per function call, that's extremely slow for such a simple function. That explains most of the runtime of your query, if you count the function calls. I'm curious to see the source code of this function... Did it really take almost 2 hours for 100k rows?

Comment: No, it didn't take 2 hours for 100k rows. The query completes in 7-8 seconds between runs. Or I didn't get your question. What did you mean by 2 hours? So yeah maybe optimizing this legacy extraction function would be a good solution at this moment.

Comment: Same result though, I misplaced the comma in both queries (lol)! 69µs, most of your query time is in that function. It takes 4µs with a regexp. You can cache the result of this function in a generated column: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html (and then you can index it if that helps some other queries)

Comment: Got it. This looks like a good improvement, definitely didn't think that calling the function might slow the whole query. Thanks!

Comment: Chances are, your function `get_root_domain()` can be optimized ...

Answer (score 1):

From our discussion in the comments, it turns out most of the time is spent in the get_root_domain() function.

Currently you have 3-4 calls per row, 2 in roots CTE and 1-2 in the query depending what the CASE does.

- Quick band-aid:

If it's a simple string function that will always return the same value for the same parameter, after checking the code to make sure, you can mark it as IMMUTABLE, either with [CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html) or [ALTER FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#:%7E:text=IMMUTABLE%20indicates%20that%20the%20function,present%20in%20its%20argument%20list.). So when it is used twice with the same parameter as in your query, postgres will only call it once.

However, it will still be called in the CTE and in the query, so this will reduce the number of calls from 3-4 to 2.

- Quick band-aid v2:

Since you're going to execute it once per row anyway, cache it in a CTE:

```
WITH ur AS (SELECT *, get_root_domain(domain) as "root_domain"
           FROM user_domains
           WHERE "user_id" = 1),
```

...then the rest of the query uses that CTE instead of table user_domains, with the pre-filled root_domain column. This will reduce the number of calls to 1.

- Check if you can optimize the function
- Put it in a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

  ALTER TABLE ... ADD root_domain TEXT
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (get_root_domain(domain)) STORED

This will lock the table during update, but once it's done it's done. You can then index the generated column if needed.

Comment: The function is declared as immutable. It's a good idea to look into this and thanks again. I was hoping that there is a pattern for queries like that when you need to exclude duplicates by a criteria and then merge it with unique values.

Comment: Not really a pattern except "if it's expensive, do it as little as possible", of which all of the points in my answer are variants lol